# Firewire 1394 camera with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, nvidia, firewire

I am trying to run face detection demo from OpenCV using firewire 1394 camera. While doing so I got the following error.

```
Unable to stop the stream.: Bad file descriptor
In capture ...
VIDIOC_STREAMON: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Unable to stop the stream.: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Here is the code for face detection demo from OpenCV

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

static void help()
{
    cout << "\nThis program demonstrates the cascade recognizer. Now you can use Haar or LBP features.\n"
            "This classifier can recognize many kinds of rigid objects, once the appropriate classifier is trained.\n"
            "It's most known use is for faces.\n"
            "Usage:\n"
            "./facedetect [--cascade=<cascade_path> this is the primary trained classifier such as frontal face]\n"
               "   [--nested-cascade[=nested_cascade_path this an optional secondary classifier such as eyes]]\n"
               "   [--scale=<image scale greater or equal to 1, try 1.3 for example>]\n"
               "   [--try-flip]\n"
               "   [filename|camera_index]\n\n"
            "see facedetect.cmd for one call:\n"
            "./facedetect --cascade=\"../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml\" --nested-cascade=\"../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml\" --scale=1.3\n\n"
            "During execution:\n\tHit any key to quit.\n"
            "\tUsing OpenCV version " << CV_VERSION << "\n" << endl;
}

void detectAndDraw( Mat& img, CascadeClassifier& cascade,
                    CascadeClassifier& nestedCascade,
                    double scale, bool tryflip );

string cascadeName = "../../data/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml";
string nestedCascadeName = "../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
    CvCapture* capture = 0;
    Mat frame, frameCopy, image;
    const string scaleOpt = "--scale=";
    size_t scaleOptLen = scaleOpt.length();
    const string cascadeOpt = "--cascade=";
    size_t cascadeOptLen = cascadeOpt.length();
    const string nestedCascadeOpt = "--nested-cascade";
    size_t nestedCascadeOptLen = nestedCascadeOpt.length();
    const string tryFlipOpt = "--try-flip";
    size_t tryFlipOptLen = tryFlipOpt.length();
    string inputName;
    bool tryflip = false;

    help();

    CascadeClassifier cascade, nestedCascade;
    double scale = 1;

    for( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
    {
        cout << "Processing " << i << " " <<  argv[i] << endl;
        if( cascadeOpt.compare( 0, cascadeOptLen, argv[i], cascadeOptLen ) == 0 )
        {
            cascadeName.assign( argv[i] + cascadeOptLen );
            cout << "  from which we have cascadeName= " << cascadeName << endl;
        }
        else if( nestedCascadeOpt.compare( 0, nestedCascadeOptLen, argv[i], nestedCascadeOptLen ) == 0 )
        {
            if( argv[i][nestedCascadeOpt.length()] == '=' )
                nestedCascadeName.assign( argv[i] + nestedCascadeOpt.length() + 1 );
            if( !nestedCascade.load( nestedCascadeName ) )
                cerr << "WARNING: Could not load classifier cascade for nested objects" << endl;
        }
        else if( scaleOpt.compare( 0, scaleOptLen, argv[i], scaleOptLen ) == 0 )
        {
            if( !sscanf( argv[i] + scaleOpt.length(), "%lf", &scale ) || scale < 1 )
                scale = 1;
            cout << " from which we read scale = " << scale << endl;
        }
        else if( tryFlipOpt.compare( 0, tryFlipOptLen, argv[i], tryFlipOptLen ) == 0 )
        {
            tryflip = true;
            cout << " will try to flip image horizontally to detect assymetric objects\n";
        }
        else if( argv[i][0] == '-' )
        {
            cerr << "WARNING: Unknown option %s" << argv[i] << endl;
        }
        else
            inputName.assign( argv[i] );
    }

    if( !cascade.load( cascadeName ) )
    {
        cerr << "ERROR: Could not load classifier cascade" << endl;
        help();
        return -1;
    }

    if( inputName.empty() || (isdigit(inputName.c_str()[0]) && inputName.c_str()[1] == '\0') )
    {
        capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( inputName.empty() ? 0 : inputName.c_str()[0] - '0' );
        int c = inputName.empty() ? 0 : inputName.c_str()[0] - '0' ;
        if(!capture) cout << "Capture from CAM " <<  c << " didn't work" << endl;
    }
    else if( inputName.size() )
    {
        image = imread( inputName, 1 );
        if( image.empty() )
        {
            capture = cvCaptureFromAVI( inputName.c_str() );
            if(!capture) cout << "Capture from AVI didn't work" << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        image = imread( "lena.jpg", 1 );
        if(image.empty()) cout << "Couldn't read lena.jpg" << endl;
    }

    cvNamedWindow( "result", 1 );

    if( capture )
    {
        cout << "In capture ..." << endl;
        for(;;)
        {
            IplImage* iplImg = cvQueryFrame( capture );
            frame = iplImg;
            if( frame.empty() )
                break;
            if( iplImg->origin == IPL_ORIGIN_TL )
                frame.copyTo( frameCopy );
            else
                flip( frame, frameCopy, 0 );

            detectAndDraw( frameCopy, cascade, nestedCascade, scale, tryflip );

            if( waitKey( 10 ) >= 0 )
                goto _cleanup_;
        }

        waitKey(0);

_cleanup_:
        cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "In image read" << endl;
        if( !image.empty() )
        {
            detectAndDraw( image, cascade, nestedCascade, scale, tryflip );
            waitKey(0);
        }
        else if( !inputName.empty() )
        {
            /* assume it is a text file containing the
            list of the image filenames to be processed - one per line */
            FILE* f = fopen( inputName.c_str(), "rt" );
            if( f )
            {
                char buf[1000+1];
                while( fgets( buf, 1000, f ) )
                {
                    int len = (int)strlen(buf), c;
                    while( len > 0 && isspace(buf[len-1]) )
                        len--;
                    buf[len] = '\0';
                    cout << "file " << buf << endl;
                    image = imread( buf, 1 );
                    if( !image.empty() )
                    {
                        detectAndDraw( image, cascade, nestedCascade, scale, tryflip );
                        c = waitKey(0);
                        if( c == 27 || c == 'q' || c == 'Q' )
                            break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cerr << "Aw snap, couldn't read image " << buf << endl;
                    }
                }
                fclose(f);
            }
        }
    }

    cvDestroyWindow("result");

    return 0;
}

void detectAndDraw( Mat& img, CascadeClassifier& cascade,
                    CascadeClassifier& nestedCascade,
                    double scale, bool tryflip )
{
    int i = 0;
    double t = 0;
    vector<Rect> faces, faces2;
    const static Scalar colors[] =  { CV_RGB(0,0,255),
        CV_RGB(0,128,255),
        CV_RGB(0,255,255),
        CV_RGB(0,255,0),
        CV_RGB(255,128,0),
        CV_RGB(255,255,0),
        CV_RGB(255,0,0),
        CV_RGB(255,0,255)} ;
    Mat gray, smallImg( cvRound (img.rows/scale), cvRound(img.cols/scale), CV_8UC1 );

    cvtColor( img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
    resize( gray, smallImg, smallImg.size(), 0, 0, INTER_LINEAR );
    equalizeHist( smallImg, smallImg );

    t = (double)cvGetTickCount();
    cascade.detectMultiScale( smallImg, faces,
        1.1, 2, 0
        //|CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT
        //|CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH
        |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
        ,
        Size(30, 30) );
    if( tryflip )
    {
        flip(smallImg, smallImg, 1);
        cascade.detectMultiScale( smallImg, faces2,
                                 1.1, 2, 0
                                 //|CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT
                                 //|CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH
                                 |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
                                 ,
                                 Size(30, 30) );
        for( vector<Rect>::const_iterator r = faces2.begin(); r != faces2.end(); r++ )
        {
            faces.push_back(Rect(smallImg.cols - r->x - r->width, r->y, r->width, r->height));
        }
    }
    t = (double)cvGetTickCount() - t;
    printf( "detection time = %g ms\n", t/((double)cvGetTickFrequency()*1000.) );
    for( vector<Rect>::const_iterator r = faces.begin(); r != faces.end(); r++, i++ )
    {
        Mat smallImgROI;
        vector<Rect> nestedObjects;
        Point center;
        Scalar color = colors[i%8];
        int radius;

        double aspect_ratio = (double)r->width/r->height;
        if( 0.75 < aspect_ratio && aspect_ratio < 1.3 )
        {
            center.x = cvRound((r->x + r->width*0.5)*scale);
            center.y = cvRound((r->y + r->height*0.5)*scale);
            radius = cvRound((r->width + r->height)*0.25*scale);
            circle( img, center, radius, color, 3, 8, 0 );
        }
        else
            rectangle( img, cvPoint(cvRound(r->x*scale), cvRound(r->y*scale)),
                       cvPoint(cvRound((r->x + r->width-1)*scale), cvRound((r->y + r->height-1)*scale)),
                       color, 3, 8, 0);
        if( nestedCascade.empty() )
            continue;
        smallImgROI = smallImg(*r);
        nestedCascade.detectMultiScale( smallImgROI, nestedObjects,
            1.1, 2, 0
            //|CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT
            //|CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH
            //|CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING
            |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
            ,
            Size(30, 30) );
        for( vector<Rect>::const_iterator nr = nestedObjects.begin(); nr != nestedObjects.end(); nr++ )
        {
            center.x = cvRound((r->x + nr->x + nr->width*0.5)*scale);
            center.y = cvRound((r->y + nr->y + nr->height*0.5)*scale);
            radius = cvRound((nr->width + nr->height)*0.25*scale);
            circle( img, center, radius, color, 3, 8, 0 );
        }
    }
    cv::imshow( "result", img );
}
```

I am using prebuilt OpenCV for Tegra. Video 4 Linux device is working properly. I can see the video from firwire 1394 camera using coriander. I am not able to debug this error. I believe it might be a wrong configuration

Comment: Can you post your code? It's quite hard to help you just with ideas

Comment: I included the code @AlessioMTX

Comment: it won't change much, but please use cv::VideoCapture and cv::Mat, not CvCapture* and IplImage*

Comment: Can you please change the code. I sill have same problem.

Comment: It takes me quiet sometime but I am able to solve the problem with the same code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code. Jetson TK1 provide untested support for firewire 1394. So at times it works and at times it doesn't. You can check [here](http://elinux.org/Jetson/mini-PCIe) as well